# Does the "blur" event fire only for HTML form objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onblur

I'm working on an interactive web application, currently set up on http://picselbocs.com/projects/goalcandy (user: demo@demo.com, password: demo). It allows you to drag items containing images and/or text from the left sidebar onto the workspace on the right and resize/edit them, among other things.

I've set up an `onblur` event handler to fire (in theory at least) when a newly created object looses focus, and for testing purposes, that handler simply makes an `alert()` call. The problem is that the handler doesn't get triggered at all. Bellow is a piece of the code used in creating those new objects:

```
obj.id = 'mesh-obj-'+current_object_id;
jqObject
    .attr('id',obj.id)
    .attr('item_no', current_object_id)
    .removeClass('dragged transparent tpl-obj no-user-select')
    .addClass('mesh-obj')
    .css({
        'z-index' : current_z_index,
        'left' : obj.position.left - mesh.position.left - mesh.borderWidth,
        'top' : obj.position.top - mesh.position.top - mesh.borderWidth,
        'right' : 'auto'
    })
    .on("focusout blur", function(event){
        alert('object lost focus'); 
    })
    .appendTo('#mesh');
```

Does the blur event only trigger for form inputs, or any HTML tag at all? If the latter, then what is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From jQuery doc: The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus. Originally, this event was only applicable to form elements, such as <input>. In recent browsers, the domain of the event has been extended to include all element types. An element can lose focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or by mouse clicks elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Could it be that the `blur` handler isn't being attached? Do you need to put a comma between `focusout, blur`?

Comment: No commas. Just separated by a space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to assign tabindex to your html elements in order to capture the blur event

html:

```
<div id="box1" class="box" tabindex="1">div 1</div>
<div id="box2" class="box" tabindex="2">div 2</div>
```

js:

```
$('.box').blur(function(){
   console.log(this)
})
```

Comment: Can you provide more details please? The tabindex property is new to me and I'm not sure how exactly it helps, or how I could use it to solve my problem.

Comment: Then use css `outline: 0` on the element to remove any ugly outlines that appear when focusing on the element.

Answer (score 2):

Blur event can be used not only on form elements.

Read this [article](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) for more information.

Comment: Which are the newer browsers? (a quick summary would be good, I love quirksmode.org, but it might not always be reachable...)

Comment: That's good to know, it's what I assumed, but it still doesn't solve my problem. Otherwise put, I still don't know why the blur event handler on the newly created elements doesn't fire.

Comment: It it better to resume that it works on all major browsers nowadays